# A simple Rspec failed in testing controller index in rails 3.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec2

Our app has a simple case for testing index in rfq controller (rails 3.1.0), it is:

```
it "should be successful" do
get 'index'
response.should be_success
end
```

we just found that the case failed because of an error in index.html.erb(it passed before though). The line of code is

```
<% @rfqs.each do |r| %>

  <td><%= r.customer.short_name %></td>

<% end %>
```

The error is:

```
1) RfqsController 'index' should be successful
Failure/Error: get 'index'
ActionView::Template::Error:
undefined method short_name' for nil:NilClass
# ./app/views/rfqs/index.html.erb:28:inblock in _app_views_rfqs_index_html_erb__624673492_53806644'
# c:in each'
# c:ineach'
# ./app/views/rfqs/index.html.erb:18:in _app_views_rfqs_index_html_erb__624673492_53806644'
# ./spec/controllers/rfqs_controller_spec.rb:16:inblock (3 levels) in '
```

However, the app has no problem to display the short_name in index page. Also in rails console, r.customer.short_name did return the short name from customer table.

In rfq model, it has association:

```
belongs_to :customer
```

The case would pass if the line of code becomes: r.customer_id, instead of r.customer.short_name. Any thoughts about the problem? Thanks.

UPDATE: problem found. It is caused by junk record in test database. After cleaning the test db, problem disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you creating your rfq.customer record? Is it possible that you have made a change to the customer model (added a new validation), such that the record is now not being created?

Comment: The customer record has been created and is pulled in for selection. When creating rfq, only customer_id is saved in rfq record. There has bee no change in customer controller. The customer_id is pulled in successfully and it can't find the customer short name associated with the customer_id

Comment: The error you are getting indicates it can't find the customer, as it is nil.

Comment: The strange thing is it can find the customer_id and rspec passes.

Comment: Could you have more than one rfq record in the rfqs variable, and one of them does not have a customer associated with it? Have you tried putting a debugger statement in the index action when running the specs to see what the rfqs variable holds?

Comment: The problem is caused by junk record in test db. Please see update in the post. Thanks.